# Issue with SplitViewController and viewWillAppear not called in Master View Controller when in portrait

Tags: ios, swift

I have followed the code here to set the Master/Detail view to show in portrait by adding the following to the Master View Controller.

```
self.splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible
```

Issue I am having is that viewWillAppear is not being called in portrait mode on my iPad, this works just fine in landscape mode. I use this method to fetch data from server.

I know I could hack something into the viewDidLoad and if iPad and Portrait to do this call but I don't think that is the correct way of doing it.

What am I missing here, sorry new to iOS programming.